# Neo4J Cypher - Getting count of a set of 3 quotes in multiple articles

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have tried achieving this multiple times but not able to so far, so posting in Stack Overflow

In my current application, we need to find the # of times different set of 3 quotes that appear together. The context is that 
An Article can consist of multiple quotes and the same quote can appear in multiple Articles, I need to find out all those quotes (in a pair of 3) that are highest in demand, trying to do this in Cypher but it seems very complicated...

Insert Queries are as below

```
CREATE (ART449211:Article {id: '449211', pages:20, author: 'MAT LONG' })
CREATE (ART559233:Article {id: '559233', pages:78, author: 'ANDREW KING' })
CREATE (ART765432:Article {id: '765432', pages:65, author: 'STEPHEN JOHN' })
CREATE (ART112244:Article {id: '112244', pages:30, author: 'REV PHILIP' })
CREATE (ART908789:Article {id: '908789', pages:40, author: 'JOE MUSK' })
CREATE (ART123321:Article {id: '123321', pages:63, author: 'KING KONG' })
CREATE (ART887651:Article {id: '887651', pages:18, author: 'LILY MATHEW' })
CREATE (ART800704:Article {id: '800704', pages:24, author: 'GEORGE L' })
CREATE (ART600333:Article {id: '600333', pages:10, author: 'SHIRIN JOHN' })

CREATE (QUOTE123456:Quote {num: '123456', name : 'QUOTE A', desc: 'QUOTE A-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE765980:Quote {num: '765980', name : 'QUOTE B', desc: 'QUOTE B-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE987681:Quote {num: '987681', name : 'QUOTE C', desc: 'QUOTE C-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE876982:Quote {num: '876982', name : 'QUOTE D', desc: 'QUOTE D-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE776983:Quote {num: '776983', name : 'QUOTE E', desc: 'QUOTE E-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE765984:Quote {num: '765984', name : 'QUOTE F', desc: 'QUOTE F-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE436724:Quote {num: '436724', name : 'QUOTE G', desc: 'QUOTE G-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE362984:Quote {num: '362984', name : 'QUOTE H', desc: 'QUOTE H-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE764444:Quote {num: '764444', name : 'QUOTE I', desc: 'QUOTE I-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE888984:Quote {num: '888984', name : 'QUOTE J', desc: 'QUOTE J-TEXT' })

CREATE (QUOTE654009:Quote {num: '654009', name : 'QUOTE K', desc: 'QUOTE K-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE431110:Quote {num: '431110', name : 'QUOTE L', desc: 'QUOTE L-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE565678:Quote {num: '565678', name : 'QUOTE M', desc: 'QUOTE M-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE009876:Quote {num: '009876', name : 'QUOTE N', desc: 'QUOTE N-TEXT' })
CREATE (QUOTE543222:Quote {num: '543222', name : 'QUOTE O', desc: 'QUOTE O-TEXT' })

CREATE
(ART449211)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE123456),
(ART449211)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765980),
(ART449211)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART449211)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART449211)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE654009),

(ART559233)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE123456),
(ART559233)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765980),
(ART559233)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART559233)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART559233)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE431110),

(ART765432)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE123456),
(ART765432)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765980),
(ART765432)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART765432)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART765432)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE565678),

(ART112244)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE123456),
(ART112244)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765980),
(ART112244)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART112244)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART112244)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE009876),

(ART908789)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART908789)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART908789)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE888984),

(ART123321)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART123321)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART123321)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE888984),

(ART887651)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE987681),
(ART887651)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE876982),
(ART887651)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE888984),

(ART800704)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765984),
(ART800704)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE436724),
(ART800704)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE362984),

(ART600333)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE765984),
(ART600333)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE436724),
(ART600333)-[:CONTAINS]->(QUOTE362984);
```

## Need the result something like below

```
Quote 123456, 765980, 987681 - present in 4 Articles
Quote 123456, 765980, 876982 - present in 4 Articles
Quote 765980, 987681, 876982 - present in 4 Articles
Quote 987681, 876982, 888984 - present in 3 Articles
Quote 765984, 436724, 362984 - present in 2 Articles
```

Basically - need to extract all sets of 3 quotes and then find out in how many articles they appear together and sort them in desc count.

Inputs pls...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
MATCH (a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q1:Quote),
      (a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q2:Quote),
      (a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q3:Quote) 
WHERE id(q1) < id(q2) AND id(q2) < id(q3) // avoid dups in different orders
RETURN q1.num, q2.num, q3.num, count(a) AS present_in 
ORDER BY present_in DESC
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/qtirxs

Comment: Thanks Wes - this is exactly what I was looking for. Also what does id(q1) mean ? How does this statement WHERE id(q1) < id (q2) AND id(q2) < id(q3) mean ?

Comment: The query thats in the Neo4J console seems working for me and that is different than what you have posted above, will take that query as final one.

Comment: MATCH (a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q1:Quote),(a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q2:Quote),(a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q3:Quote) WHERE id(q1)< id(q2) AND id(q2)< id(q3) RETURN q1.num, q2.num, q3.num, count(a) AS present_in ORDER BY present_in DESC

Comment: Right, I forgot I switched it to "num" instead of "name".

Comment: id() returns the node id of the node. The WHERE ensures that you won't have duplicate sets of 3, because it ensures that the id of q1 is always the lowest of the three, the id of q2 is in the middle, and the id of q3 is the highest. You could do it with another unique identifier, but if you don't care about the order, this is probably the fastest. Also, don't forget to accept. :)

Comment: On this query MATCH (a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q1:Quote),(a:Article)-[:CONTAINS]->(q2:Quote),(a:Artic‌​le)-[:CONTAINS]->(q3:Quote) WHERE id(q1)< id(q2) AND id(q2)< id(q3) RETURN q1.num, q2.num, q3.num, count(a) AS present_in ORDER BY present_in DESC, how can I access property of relationship i.e. CONTAINS.numofquotes and then add them together for each result ?

Comment: When I try accessing via [r:CONTAINS] I get an error as - Invalid query - Can't re-use pattern relationship 'r' with different start/end nodes.

Comment: Nope. You'd have to put r1/r2/r3, otherwise it won't be able to match different ones.